# How to pipe filenames with spaces from a list file into "grep"?

Tags: shell, text-processing, filenames, cygwin

First, I think the fact that I'm using cygwin is highly relevant here.

In theory, I already know how to do this:

```
cat file | xargs grep pattern
```

The problem is, some of the file paths in `file` have spaces. The file looks like this:

```
subdir/foo/bar.html
subdir/f o o/ba r.html
subdir/~foo/bar.html
```

This causes errors. I read how to solve this: use `xargs -0`. But I don't know how to make `cat` output null terminated line endings, so i think that means it squashes the whole file into one line. As a result, it gives this error:

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

**Update:** it turned out the file I was reading from had some paths that no longer exist. Coincidentally, all of these paths had a `~` in them, so I mistakenly thought that that was an issue. Turns out those files simply didn't exist. Everything about the spaces still stands though.

Comment: @cas the file doesn't contain patterns, the file contains paths to files i want to search. It's the output of a `find`

Comment: ah, okay.   is it one line per filename?  if so, use `xargs -d '\n' grep  pattern < file`.    better yet, since it's the output of `find`, use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 grep pattern`

Comment: @DanielKaplan You mentioned having problems with `~`.  Is the problem that `xargs` is trying to expand them (even when you don't want it to)?

Comment: `~` has no special meaning in the middle of a path. At the beginning, `~/` means the current user's home directory, and `~username/` means that user's home directory. What do you intend with `subdir/~foo`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `xargs -d '\n'` if the input file contains one filename per line.  e.g.

```
xargs -d '\n' grep pattern < file
```

If your filenames start with `~` to indicate "my home directory", you first need to replace the `~` symbols with your actual home directory.  For example:

```
sed -e "s=^~=$HOME=" file | xargs -d '\n' grep pattern
```

Note that this sed script is double-quoted because we *want* to interpolate the variable `$HOME` into the sed script, and uses `=` as the delimiter for the `s` operator because `$HOME` is going to contain /s (but is unlikely to contain an `=`).

Or, if you're using `find`, use find's `-print0` option combined with xargs' `-0` option.  e.g.

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 grep pattern
```

or just use find's `-exec` option:

```
find ... -exec grep pattern {} +
```

Comment: Only that first one is useful to me as I can no longer use find to get the same file list. But when I tried it, it seemed to have trouble with filenames that have ~ in it.

Comment: @Kusalananda that gave me this error `xargs: -: No such file or directory`

Comment: @DanielKaplan You'll always have issues with pathnames containing `~` as this is something that the shell needs to expand. You may need to insert an explicit substitution from `~` to whatever your home directory path is.

Comment: `~` only has meaning to the shell (and some other programs written to interpret it as $HOME, which is far from universal).    Try `xargs -d '\n' grep pattern < <(sed -e "s=~=$HOME=" file)`.   or `sed -e "s=~=$HOME=" file | xargs -d '\n' grep pattern`

Comment: BTW, it's unusual for the output of `find` to contain `~` characters.   If I run `find ~/` on my system, I get output lines starting with `/home/cas/`, not with `~/`.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, that's true. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: @cas the paths themselves have a `~` in them. e.g., `./foo/~bar/baz.html`

Comment: @DanielKaplan, so this use of tilde is that ~bar is user bar's home directory, and you need to refer to various users' home directories?

Comment: See the update to my OP

Answer (score 3):

Another answer mentioned `xargs -d '\n'`, which is the preferred solution.  (In my opinion it's so preferred that it's what `xargs` should do by *default*, but that's another story.)

But not all versions of `xargs` support `-d`.  If you're stuck with one that doesn't, you can try

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file | xargs -0 grep pattern
```

(Once upon a time there were versions of `tr` that unaccountably could not substitute null characters like this, but you're unlikely to come across one of those versions today.)

Comment: What `tr` implementation wouldn't?

Comment: All those before GNU's, if I remember correctly.  [This V7 man page](https://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/1/tr) mentions the bug explicitly.  (But I do agree: it's astonishing that the bug lasted for any amount of time without being fixed.)

Comment: POSIX requires `tr '\n' '\0'` to work, I don't expect you'll find a system today where that won't work. On BSDs, it was [fixed in 1988](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/commit/633de41095a17edd1bfc4ee02d30ed2972e5612b)

Comment: `tr` was added to GNU textutils in December 1991 (first released in textutils 1.2 in 1992), so it's not about GNU.

Comment: @Stéphane Good point about POSIX.  I've adjusted the parenthetical (and arguably, if I weren't such an incorrigible packrat, I ought to have deleted it outright).

Answer (score 1):

Remember: `xargs` will put the whole content of file as command line arguments to grep ... The error you met is probably due to too much filename in your file resulting in a commmand line too long.

If you want to search for files which content match pattern, i propose the following iterative method:

```
gcolangelo@debian-test:/tmp$ cat test_files 
/dir1/file1 with space
/dir2/file2 with space
/dir3 with space/file3

gcolangelo@debian-test:/tmp$ while read filepath ; do echo "-- coin ${filepath} --" ; done < test_files 
-- coin /dir1/file1 with space --
-- coin /dir2/file2 with space --
-- coin /dir3 with space/file3 --
-- coin  --
```

Comment: The first sentence is true if you add "when using nul as the delimiter, since the file does not contain any nuls".

Comment: `xargs` should never create a command line too long. It will split up the input into batches that fit the allowed length.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a file grep -- pattern
```

`-r`, `-d`, `-a`, `-0` are all GNU extensions. Some other `xargs` have copied some of those, most commonly `-0`, sometimes `-r`, rarely `-a` and `-d`.

`-r` and `-0` will be added in the specification of the `xargs` utility in the next version of the POSIX standard.

```
<file tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r0 grep -- pattern
```

Would work with many `xargs` implementations, with the caveat that `grep`'s stdin is now either the pipe or `/dev/null`. Not a problem for this `grep` invocation, but could be for other commands.

You can remove the `-r` if your `xargs` doesn't support it, that means that if `file` is empty, `grep` will end up called without filename argument and will read from its stdin, but that would be fine here as it would find nothing. It could be a problem with other commands or here if using the `-L` option to `grep`:

```
$ : empty | xargs -r0 grep -L whatev
$ : empty | xargs -0 grep -L whatev
(standard input)
```

POSIXly (with implementations conforming to the current version of the specification as of May 2023), if the `file` is meant to contain text in the user's locale encoding (but file paths have no guarantee to be text), and lines are no longer than 255 bytes, you can do

```
{
  <file sed 's/"/"\\""/g; s/.*/"&"/' 3<&- |
    xargs -E '' sh -c '
      [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec grep -- pattern "$@" <&3 3<&-
    ' sh
} 3<&0
```

Where

- `sed` wraps lines in double quotes, escaping the quotes if any as the equivalent of `-d '\n'`,
- `-E ''` is need to prevent the special handling of a `_` word that some `xargs` implementations still do and POSIX still allows
- `sh` is used to not run the command if there's no argument as an equivalent of `-r` and to restore stdin as equivalent of `-a`.
- note that some `xargs` implementations have a ridiculously low limit (255) on the length of an argument as allowed by POSIX, and require the input to be text, choking if it isn't.

In any case, newline is as valid a character as any in a file path, so you can't represent an arbitrary list of file paths with your `file` format (one file path per text line). A NUL-delimited list is one way to represent an arbitrary list of file paths or command line arguments, hence the `-0` supported by most `xargs`s.

The `--` is needed for GNU `grep` and some other non-POSIX-compliant `grep` implementations that accept options after non-options, with `grep -e pattern --`, it's needed in any `grep` implementation.

Also beware that `grep` only prefixes matches with the name of the file if passed more than one file path to look into. As `xargs` will break the list as required to fit in the `execve()` limit, there's no guarantee the last batch won't have only 1 file (and `file` could also have only one line). You can work around it by adding `/dev/null` as one of the files to look into (`xargs ... grep -- pattern /dev/null`) or if using GNU `grep` or compatible, pass the `-H` option. `-h` (also a GNU extension) to never include the file path, or portably use `xargs ... cat | grep pattern`.

Also beware that `grep` won't read from a file called `-`, reading from stdin instead in that case. Can be worked around by changing its path to `./-`, for instance by adding `s|^-$|./-|` at the beginning of the `sed` code above.

With zsh, you can also do:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -r --eof='' -- ${(f)"$(<file)"} '' grep -- pattern
```

And filter out the paths to files that don't exist or are inaccessible by appending a `N` glob qualifier to each path:

```
zargs -r --eof='' -- ${(f)^"$(<file)"}(N) '' grep -- pattern
```

Or using `xargs -r0`:

```
print -rNC1 -- ${(f)^"$(<file)"}(N) | xargs -r0 grep -- pattern
```

(you could also add the `.` qualifier to restrict to regular files (or `-.` to also consider symlinks to regular files)).

With GNU findutils 4.9 or newer and a shell with ksh-style process substitution support, you can do something similar with:

```
find -files0-from <(tr '\n' '\0' < file) -prune -xtype f \
  -exec grep -- pattern
```

`-xtype f` to filter-out files that are not regular files, but note that `find` will still complain about files it cannot access.

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts it might be beneficial to use a `while` loop instead of `xargs` (e.g. when you want to do execute more than one command):

```
while IFS= read -r file <&3
do
    grep -- pattern "$file" 3<&-
done 3< file
```

Though beware it calls one `grep` per file.